# Is "in-TEST-eyen" a valid pronunciation for "intestine"?

Tags: pronunciation, canadian-english, diphthongs

Is "in-TEST-eyen" /ɪnˈtestaɪn/ a valid pronunciation for "intestine"? I looked up "intestine" in [MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/intestine), [Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/intestine), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intestine), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intestine?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) and even the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, none of which recommends that pronunciation. However, I've heard at least two Canadians use it (Matthew Santoro and one of those guys on ASAP Science on YouTube). I have no access to any Canadian English dictionary.

So, is "in-TEST-eyen" /ɪnˈtestaɪn/ a valid (**common and accepted as correct, not as a mispronunciation**) pronunciation for "intestine"? Or is it just valid in Canada? Or did those Canadians simply mispronounce it?

---

Link to Mathew Santoro's [Useless Body Parts You Have For No Reason](https://youtu.be/Nn7ha1kSvNA?t=5m31s) video

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn7ha1kSvNA That's the Matthew Santoro video. I don't remember the ASAP Science video though, but I can assure that he said in-TEST-eyen a lot in it.

Comment: What do you think makes a pronunciation valid or invalid?

Comment: @sumelic if it's clearly commonplace and recommended by most dictionaries, especially pronunciation dictionaries, yes. Otherwise, there's a good chance it's just a mispronunciation.

Comment: @sumelic For instance, even though he doesn't really endorse them, John C. Wells still included common variants for Caribbean and sloth in his dictionary, which is proof that they're commonplace and acceptable.

Comment: All pronunciations are valid if sincere and the spoken with confidence.

Comment: @jlovegren By your logic, there's no such thing as "mispronunciation", and there will be no "model" to follow. People can just start to pronounce words however the hell they want.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw They cannot. People do whatever the hell they want in general, but they're not able to extensively make up totally deviant pronunciations. a vowel shift here or there or something light, but (1) talking is hard; and (2) the communication system can only tolerate so much noise.

Comment: @jlovegren "All pronunciations are valid if sincere and the spoken with confidence" You said nothing about a vowel shift. Maybe you failed to be articulate, because your first argument is quite the opposite of your second one. I do understand that if there are enough people who make the same "mistake" (either in grammar or vocabulary) within a native language (or the "standard" variety of it, that is), to the point that it becomes a trend, there'll be a **shift**, and new standards will be set.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw the first is the slogan, the second is the fine print.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw - People can pronounce words however the hell they want regardless of what anyone says.  Whether others will choose to listen depends more on whether they have something important to say than how "proper" their English is.

Comment: @jlovegren I have a friend who, for whatever reason, has always pronounced _quinoa_ as /kuːˡnoɪə/. She does so quite sincerely and with confidence. Would you not consider that a totally deviant pronunciation? Would you consider it a valid?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes it's valid, and only a little deviant. looks like she's analogizing from *paranoia*. i'd advise you to keep your distance from this person, though, you might start imitating her.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regional or dialectical pronunciation of the word... typical Canadian. It is no more a mispronunciation than the non-rhotic "pahh-keeng ya cahh in Bahh-sten."

One of my favorite Canadian pronunciations is for **the city of Regina, Saskatchewan**. It's very quaint and a bit contagious once you hear it. The vowel sounds for the ***i*** in *Regina* and the second ***i*** in *intestine* are pronounced virtually the same by many Canadians. (Long "I" like the dipthonged word "aye" or the pronoun "I")

The majority of English speakers say "reh-JEE-nah" and "in-TEST-in," both of which could be used to detect a non-Canadian accent.

Comment: The majority say /rəˈdʒi:nə/? Really? Or just Americans? Please do back up that claim. And arguably, if Canadians pronounce their city /rəˈdʒaɪnə/ then that's correct and the "majority" is wrong.

Comment: I'm American, not Candian, but "Regina" with /aɪ/ doesn't seem quaint to me; it seems eminently reasonable. Exactly comparable to "Carolina" or "vagina" (in fact, avoiding that similarity might be part of the reason some people use /i:/ instead).

Comment: In the regions of the US where I am from (primarily the South but also the Northeast and Midwest), there are some women I know named Regina. They have all been pronounced in the second syllable with /i:/  (EE) to rhyme with blue jean. My experience with the Canadian /ai/ to rhyme with vagina caught me off guard. (I first heard it from a native Canadian in passing.) This would appear to be a surprising and unusual accent to my ears, just as the original questioner described with intestine. I should have said, "the majority of American English speakers, in my experience..."

Comment: If you look at the Wikipedia entry for Regina, Saskatchewan, notice the accepted pronunciation in the article's lead. This implies that this pronunciation is somewhat unusual. Being a French (originally Latin) word, the /i:/ is apparently common for French and Slavic pronunciations, like https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Regina_Spektor

Comment: In England Regina rhymes with vagina, both have the 'ahy'' sound for the second syllable. I've never heard Regina pronounced with an 'ee' sound in England.

Comment: Then Anglo-Canada --> intest(-ay)n, Reg(-ay)na. England --> intest(-i)n, Reg(-ay)na... America --> intest(-i)n, Reg(-ee)na. That's interesting. As far as I can tell, the French speakers (of Canada or France) might agree with the Latin Régina in which the i is /i:/ . There is a Régina in French Guiana. The accented syllable is different from the American pronunciation, but would sound similar.

Comment: @uruiamme "Regina" still appears very much Latin because it's barely nativized, and it's much more regular to rhyme it with "vagina" (long Latin /i:/ > Middle English /i:/ > modern English /ai/). "re-JEE-nuh" itself, albeit more common, is the odd one, phonologically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Canadian English has its own peculiarities and differences  in pronounciation with respect to BrE and AmE are not uncommon. ***[Intestine](http://whatsdifferentincanada.tumblr.com/post/52381433724/intestines)***  is one of those:

> - Somehow Canadians have found a way to make intestines sound even more gross - the last syllable rhymes with “vines” instead of “wins."

***[The pronunciation of Canadian English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/the-pronunciation-of-canadian-english) :***

> - ***We can find the linguistic expression of the Canadian east-west connection at all linguistic levels.***  Vowels, for instance, love to change but when they change in Canada they have been shown to rarely – for some changes never—cross the Canada-US border. For example, the ‘Canadian shift’, first detected in the mid 1990s, affects the ‘short front vowels’.....
> - ***Other features include ‘Canadian raising’,***  the most-widely known Canadian pronunciation feature.  Canadian raising affects the diphthongs in words such as wife, price, or life and house, about, or shout. Canadian pronunciations, though far from universal, are often perceived as weef instead of wife and a boot instead of about by outsiders......

Oxford Dictionaty

Comment: In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIMs6CkK4PA) it says that **inTESTahyn** is American, go and figure. Anfd in Forvo the  Australian and the Canadian speaker both pronounce the letter i as "ahy"

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I've seen that, but all dictionaries show  the same pronounciation as in BrE. I have no access to Canadian dictionaries, but there is a lot of material (blogs etc.) that confirms the Canadian pronounciation.

Answer (score -1):

As a native Canadian who has lived in Canada for 40 years, in California for 8 years, in Texas for 6 years and in Florida for 2 years, I can say with high confidence that intestine and Regina are usually pronounced "in-TEST-(eye)n" and "ree-J(EYE)-na" in Canada.  Same pronunciation for intestine most places in USA too.  Sometimes intestine is pronounced like "in-TEST-in". Intestine is almost never pronounced like "in-TEST-een" except by those with foreign dialects.   Regina, for anyone who associates the name with the city, is usually pronounced "Ree-J(EYE)-na" in both USA and Canada. As a woman's name, it could be pronounced either way in Canada, but most often as "Re-JEE-na" in the US, especially by foreign English speakers and hispanics.

Comment: Hi Jim,  I see there are actually some slight differences between this and your earlier answer... There should be an "edit" option beneath your original post (on the left side, opposite your name), so that you can make updates to the answer directly instead of posting a near-duplicate.

Comment: Hi @Jim Ferguson, do you have any source(s) you can cite to back up this assertion? I know it comes from personal experience, but is there any research which concurs?